# How can HTML be allowed in Author Bio?

Tags: author, html

Is there a way to prevent WP from stripping the HTML from the author bio? I need it to keep my paragraphs.

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit - Although this question has been answered, I will clarify that I was referring to the Bio textarea when editing individual users.

Comment: The WYSIWYG editor allows html in WordPress so are you referring to some author bio input elsewhere? Please be a bit more specific where you mean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove the filter that formats the description. put this in your theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

EDIT - I should mention, if you allow random people to register and add their own bio for display on the site, not filtering that text could enable bad things.

Comment: Oh, excellent! The solutions I was finding were about editing the core, and this will be much better! Thanks!

Comment: Why not *add* a more permissive filter after removing the default filter? e.g. `add_filter( 'pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );` that way, user-input content isn't completely unsanitized.