# WordPress strips some attributes for author posts

Tags: posts, user-roles, customization

I added template to my WP posts, so when you click Add New content area alreday with text.
Template smt. like this

```
<div id="myDiv"><p>Add your text here</p></div>
```

If user has Admin or Editor roles then it works great, but if user has Author role id sprips, and I got

```
<div><p>Add your text here</p></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, and you've posted no code for us to look at, until you do there's nothign we can do to help.  If you could post the code that generates that markup and provide a little more context?

Comment: It's standard WP, I don't know what code I need to post, because can't find where is the problem... Probably this is not the problem, just WP specific.

If you try to login like author, then go to adding post, insert onto HTML editor something like this '<div id="test"><b>sdasd</b></div>' you will se the problem 'id="test"' will be stripped.

Comment: Please let me know if some parts not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP stripts HTML for authors. I had this problem too. I'm sure this post can help you. [How can HTML be allowed in Author Bio?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21326/how-can-html-be-allowed-in-author-bio) or this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/authors-can-not-embed-video#post-1483017