# Allow Profile HTML for select users

Tags: filters, security, profiles

I know there are a ton of post out there about how to allow html in profiles. Most of these warn about the security risk of doing so. My thinking is there has to be a way to only allow users to use html for certain users. I tried this but It doesn't work. I think it's because you can't remove a filter from inside a filter. Any help would be awesome.

```
add_action('edit user profile update', 'nifty_strip_html');

 function nifty_strip_html($user_id) {
     if ($user_id == 2){
        //if user id is 2 then allow html
        remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');

        }
      else{
            return; //keep the filtered html
      }
  }
```

Comment: You could try this for all users: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21326/how-can-html-be-allowed-in-author-bio#comment28555_21328

Comment: @birgire Yeah I know, but I'd rather just be on the safe side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook on an early action and apply the filter for your use case:

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'allow_profile_html_wpse_91564' );

function allow_profile_html_wpse_91564()
{
    global $current_user;
    if( '2' == $current_user->ID )
        remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
}
```

The hook [**`load-$pagenow`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L215) runs in all default admin pages (i.e., not added by a third party), and it's declared in the file `/wp-admin/admin.php`.

`$pagenow` is the PHP page running at a given moment. So, to target the page `/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=2`, another hook is needed and also another conditional checking:

```
add_action( 'load-user-edit.php', 'callback_function' );

function allow_user_html_wpse_91564()
{        
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['user_id'] ) && '2' == $_REQUEST['user_id'] )
        remove_filter( 'pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );    
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. What page is `load-profile.php`? I'm trying to edit the user inside of the admin so i tried to change the hook to `edit-user.php` but still didn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer, my first example was only for the profile page. And, for editing an user, another conditional is needed.